# Java JDBC clearBatch() and heap memory

Tags: java, oracle, memory, jdbc, batch-processing

I've noticed the following behavior.

I have a file that is about 3MB containing several thousand rows.
In the rows I split and create prepared statement (about 250 000 statements).

What I do is:

```
preparedStatement
addBatch
do for every 200 rows {
 executeBatch
 clearBatch().
}
```

at the end

```
commit()
```

The memory usage will increase to around 70mb without out of memory error. Is it possible get the memory usage down? and have the transactional behavior (if one fails all fails.).
I was able to lower the memory by doing commit with the `executeBatch` and `clearBatch`... but this will cause a partial insert of the total set.

Comment: This could be very dependent on the quality of the JDBC driver - which one are you using?

Comment: I've changed from 200 rows to 10000 and the time to execute is now 37 seconds. It looks like the same size is used.

I am using the H2's org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool the data is stored as a file.. not in memory.

I am trying to build a local application without a database server like oracle, mysql, etc.

Comment: Are you certain that the high memory usage is related to the database processing, and not to the file I/O from the import?

Comment: No your right, the biggest memory usage is due to h2 database...

I rewrote my junit to use oracle and it takes about 17/18MB all the time (from begin till end). I am just wondering if 17 or 18 mb is big with a file of 2MB and 250K inserts.

I think it will be difficult to reduce the amount of memory with h2 in it anyone a suggestion to use something similar with less memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

You could insert all rows into a temp table with same structure and if everything is fine. let the database insert them into to target table using: `insert into target (select * from temp)`. 
In case the import into the temp table fails you haven't changed anything in you target table.

EDIT: fixed syntax

Answer (score -1):

You could also use the JDBC 2.0 "batch processing" feature.

1. Set your dbconnection using `connection.setAutoCommit(false)`
2. Add batches to your statement using `statement.addBatch(sql_text_here)`
3. Once your batches are all loaded, execute it using: `statement.executeBatch()`
4. Commit it using `connection.commit()`
5. Catch exceptions and rollback as necessary using `connection.rollback()`

More on exception handling for rollback... here is a typical rollback exception handler:

```
  catch( BatchUpdateException bue )
  {
    bError = true;
    aiupdateCounts = bue.getUpdateCounts();

    SQLException SQLe = bue;
    while( SQLe != null)
    {
      // do exception stuff

      SQLe = SQLe.getNextException();
    }
  } // end BatchUpdateException catch
  catch( SQLException SQLe )
  {
    ...

  } // end SQLException catch
```

Read up here: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Database/JDBC20Intro/JDBC20.html#JDBC2015

Comment: Isn't that what he described he does presently except using prepared statements  ?

Comment: Partially, yes (steps 1-4). But step 5 will allow a complete rollback of the transaction if it fails.

Comment: Rollback isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: OP states:  "Is it possible get the memory usage down? and have the transactional behavior (if one fails all fails.)" so yes, rollback of the transaction is relevant to the problem.